# Hot Reloading in Flutter not Working When running in Physical Device

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, flutter-channel

I'm using Android Studio to Develop Flutter Apps. When I run the App in Emulator I'm able to Hot Reload but when using Physical Device, Hot Reload, Flutter Hot Restart, Timeline View and Flutter Inspector buttons are disabled. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Check this Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the corresponding platform tool for your device system version

Comment: Finally It works. I just downgraded the platform-tools from 28.0.1 to 28.0.0.